# WPF Image problem with loading URL sources

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, wpf, multithreading

I have a code that has 4 background workers that are getting image url's from my database. Each have a foreach loop that gets the database results into a list. Then images are created on the run with this code.

```
this.Bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri( -URL- , UriKind.Absolute));
Bitmap.DownloadCompleted += new EventHandler( -Event Below- );
```

And the event checks whether it has any image on it or not (because there is always an image, but empty if the link is not valid), printing "No image" text if there is none.

```
if (((BitmapImage)sender).Width > 1)
    this.AddChild(Image);
else
    this.AddChild(new TextBlock() { Text = "No Image Available" });
```

This kind of works with my mocked lists. But a problem occurs when I have a longer query that takes more time to run. So, some of the images are missing and there are no text generated on them. But some are okay and works perfectly. Here's my sqlHandler class too, if my reader is the problem.

```
MySqlDataReader reader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
{
    while(reader.Read())
    //Get stuff
...
```

And here is the background worker doWork method:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            foreach (Book book in list)
            {
                if (book != null)
                    wrapPopular.Children.Add(new object_that_generates_the_bitmap);
            }
        });
```

I'm guessing it's a thread problem but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: You should not use BackgroundWorker. Have a look at TPL and async/await

Comment: Besides that you should only attach a DownloadCompleted handler if IsDownloading is actually true. Otherwise, the BitmapImage is already loaded when the constructor returns.

Comment: @SirRufo I know about them, but never used them before. I'll do more research and see if it helps my case. Thanks.